# jquery disable a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

For one of my projects we have a proprietary CMS that works by looking for a file in the clients instance directory first and if not found, it defaults to the common directory. So in the common directory, i have shell.js which includes a function for setting the initial state of a collapse div in bootstrap 2.3.2. I need to be able to disable this function at the client level while still having the function available in the common level. Im pretty green at js/jquery, can someone help me?

The code in the shell.js is this...

```
/*******************************/
/*  TOGGLE BUTTON
/*******************************/
var toggleBlock = function() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width(),
        isDesktop = windowsize > 765;

    $("#quicksearch").toggleClass("collapse in", isDesktop);
    $("#quicksearch").toggleClass("collapse out", !isDesktop);
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapse in", isDesktop);
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapse out", !isDesktop);
}
$(document).ready(toggleBlock);
$(window).on("resize.showContent", toggleBlock);
toggleBlock();
```

would .unbind() be the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty crude solution:

```
  var disabledFlag = false;

  var toggleBlock = function() {
    if(!disabledFlag){
      var windowsize = $(window).width(),
      isDesktop = windowsize > 765;

      $("#quicksearch").toggleClass("collapse in", isDesktop);
      $("#quicksearch").toggleClass("collapse out", !isDesktop);
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapse in", isDesktop);
      $("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapse out", !isDesktop);
   }
}
```

Then elsewhere in the code you flip the flag to true, which will stop the function from executing the meaningful code:

```
 disabledFlag = true;
```

Comment: i changed the code in my shell.js and then added <script>var disabledFlag = true;</script> in the head section of index.html and its not working...something i'm doing wrong? By setting the var disableFlag to true, i need the default state to be collapsed?

Comment: Did you add that block after `shell.js`? It would need to come before.

Comment: now have it before the shell.js and still loading page with the collapse expanded.